# Int to string - Saving back to a database from a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am saving values from a textbox back to a database. How do I save a number entered in a textbox back to the database. I have tried the following but get an error saying `Input string was not in a correct format`

```
newCarsRow.CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text);
//I have also tried
newCarsRow.CustomerID = int.Parse(TextBox5.Text);
```

I am saving text entered into the textbox like so

```
newCarsRow.Surname = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
```

Comment: customerid is numeric field ?

Comment: What do you get in `TextBox5.Text`, its not a number

Comment: What have you entered as number? You have to handle empty values separately by setting DBNull value as well.

Comment: I am not able to get to the webpage. The error is shown before the page is loaded.

Comment: where you have wrritten this code

Comment: try to use TextBox5.Text.Trim(), may be Space is having some Problem

Comment: @joshuahornby10 show your code of button click and texbox asxpx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using

```
newCarsRow.CustomerID = int.Parse(TextBox5.Text);
```

you should try using

```
int customerID = 0;
if(int.TryParse(TextBox5.Text.Trim(), out customerID))
{
  newCarsRow.CustomerID = customerID;
}
else
{
  // Customer id received from the text box is not a valid int. Do relevant error processing
}
```

Now you wont get the Exception you were previously facing, and also would be able to perform the relevant error handling.

Answer (score 1):

IF newCarsRow.CustomerID is Int, may be Space is having some Problem.

then Try this

```
newCarsRow.CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text.Trim());
```

Comment: I get an error saying Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: can u debug the Value TextBox5.Text before execute the Line, tell me waht is the type of CustomerID

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is related to number format?

Try to use [Int32.TryParse(string, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, out int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf50za27%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) specifying the [NumberStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and as [IFormatProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) use [NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currentinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).